# Is there a way to use nested pojo's inside a hql query?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, hql

This is a small example of what i am trying to accomplish.

```
@Query("select new ksa.so.beans.PojoMain("
            + " PojoName(il.title),"
            + " PojoNumber(il.item.id)"
            + ") "
            + "From ItemLanguage il where il.id = 13751 and il.language.id = 1")
    PojoMain testingNestedPojo();
```

any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can't use nested pojos inside HQL.

But you can use projections instead of pojos. There're lots of tutorials like [this one](https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/spring-framework/spring-data/interface-based-nested-projections.html)

> Projection:
>
> ```
> public interface EmployeeInfo {
>   String getName();
>   int getSalary();
>   DeptInfo getDepartment();
>
>   interface DeptInfo {
>       String getDeptName();
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> And in repository:
>
> ```
> public interface EmployeeRepository extends CrudRepository<Employee, Long> {
>   List<EmployeeInfo> findBy();
>   List<EmployeeInfo> findBySalaryBetween(int salaryMin, int salaryMax);
>   List<EmployeeInfo> findByDepartmentLocation(String location);
> }
> ```